# what is difference between AVCapture and camera default of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, avcapturesession, avcapture, avcam

my app use AVCapture for capture image, this is my supervisor's ideal. But i research in internet and a can't get any information about the difference between AVCapture and default camera of iPhone or iPop (tab focus or camera quality...). please tell me what advance of AVFoundation framework ...

Answer (score 3):

with the AVCaptureSession you can give your recorder a lot more functionality. You can customize nearly every aspect of the recording session. and you can ever get the raw data straight from the camera. the code can get quite complex however, and nothing is taken care of for you.

With the iOS default image capture controller you will be stuck with a few presets, and you will only have a little bit of camera functionality. But it is really simple to implement.

## updated with link to apple code

If you want to see how to use the AVFoundation to do you camera recording you will probably like this app from apple.

Like I said, you will have to do everything manually. so be prepared for a handful of work.

[AVCam demo app by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010112)

Comment: first, thanks for answer. Somebody says that the iOS default camera not support tab focus with iOS 5.x, so we have to use AVcamera to use this function. But i have just test with my iPhone 3gs iOS 5.1.1, with default camera tab focus function work well, however i see that the AVCamera is not work tab focus with iPop 4.1 iOS 5.1.1... so any ideal about that

Comment: I am not sure what tab focus is. but if you want a good example I will update the post with a good apple example of a camera app.